# Recreating jQuery live/on in pure JS

Tags: javascript

I am making a todo list webapp in pure JS (trying not to use jQuery!) and I'm struggling on one aspect, attaching a click handler onto an element I've just created. Here is the creation code:

```
new_li = document.createElement('li');
new_li.innerHTML = item.value;
new_li.setAttribute('rel', time);
prependElement(tudu_list, new_li);
```

This happens onclick of a button.

I need to attach a click handler onto every LI in a UL. But nothing happens when I click a newly created LI. I'm guessing its an issue where there is no click handler bound to the element. In jQuery I would normally do .live(), but in JS, I have no idea how to get around this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is:

```
function clickHandler(){
    // Do something...
}

new_li = document.createElement('li');
new_li.innerHTML = item.value;
new_li.setAttribute('rel', time);
new_li.onclick = clickHandler; // <===========
prependElement(tudu_list, new_li);
```

Of course you can (and should) use `addEventListener` instead of inline scripts:

```
new_li.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
```

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the pointer. What do you mean by "instead of inline scripts."?

Comment: @benhowdle89. Meaning putting the callback of the events in the element `onclick` attribute and property.

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'AddEventListener'.

Comment: @benhowdle89. I'm sorry, I wrote `Add` instead of `add`. I fixed it. sorry

Answer (score 3):

Attach event handler to `<ul>` element, then check event's `target` attribute - if it is one of `<li>` elements, then execute the event handler, otherwise just skip it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target

Comment: This is really how `on` works, but because **he** creates the elements, he can attach the callbacks to the newly created elements. Don't you think?

Comment: @gdoron: Yes, you are right, he _can_ do this. But you proposed that already, I have just proposed the way to actually do "_Recreating jQuery live/on in pure JS_", don't you think?